# Is there a commonly used MIME type for Thrift?

Tags: mime-types, thrift

If not, "application/x-thrift" could be an option (inspired on http://www.slideshare.net/mokeefe/javaone-2009-ts5276-restful-protocol-buffers). Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official IANA media types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) for Thrift are:

- [application/vnd.apache.thrift.binary](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.apache.thrift.binary)
- [application/vnd.apache.thrift.compact](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.apache.thrift.compact)
- [application/vnd.apache.thrift.json](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.apache.thrift.json)

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: please see more up to date response from Jon Parise.

Took me a while to confirm this so I'm ending up answering to my own question. In the Thrift .NET runtime library, class Thrift.Transport.THttpClient I found "request.ContentType = "application/x-thrift";"

So it appears my assumption matches the recommendation.